# why tablelayoutpanel corrupts at design time?

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I am using a TableLayoutPanel in my Windows Forms application with 5 columns and 10 rows. I have added all the required controls and everything was working fine, but suddenly the TableLayoutPanel started behaving oddly.

For example, when I try to add a new column to the TableLayoutPanel, it appears to be added successfully but it is not being displayed. I have checked that the column's size mode is set to Absolute, so it should be visible.

This issue is occurring during design time using the Visual Studio designer, so there is no code involved yet. This is not the first time that I have encountered problems with the TableLayoutPanel at design time, and I have had to remove and re-add the control in the past where an other tlp became unable to resize columns using the mouse, alot of problems with tlp causing me to wonder is there any one resolved this because it is really annoying and causing work to be lost some how.

I would like to know why this is happening and if there is any way to fix it permanently, as this is causing significant disruptions to my workflow.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Comment: Please provide a minimum achievable use case. Also, do you use properties such as dock, AutoSize, Margin extensively in the designer